# How to passing variable from controller to view queued mail?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to pass variable $array from controller to mail blade, but whenever I run queue:listen. It always say failed.

Bellow is my code

In controller I have a variable named $array, I've putting it in dispatch

Controller

```
$array["view"] = "layouts.mail.order";
$array["subject"] = "Order Created";
$array["from"] = env('MAIL_USERNAME');
$array["data"] = "aaaaaaaaa";
$array["email"] = Auth::user()->email;
OrderEmailJob::dispatch($array);
```

OrderEmailJob

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\OrderMail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class OrderEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $array;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($array)
    {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new OrderMail();
        Mail::to($this->array['email'])->send($array);
    }
}
```

and this is code for the mailable

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrderMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $array;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($array)
    {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view($this->array['view'])
            ->from($this->array['from'], env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'))
            ->subject($this->array['subject'])
            ->with([
                'data' => $this->array['data'],
            ]);
    }
}
```

The result I want is I can use variable $array in view for my mail, because I've to printed out data from $array variable

Sorry about my english, thanks

Comment: `$email = new OrderMail();` You aren't passing anything to the constructor, why would you expect to have access to a variable you don't pass?

Answer (score -1):

try like this :

```
public $mailData;

public function __construct($mailData)
{
    $this->mailData = $mailData;
}
public function build()
{
    // Array for Blade
    $input = array(
                      'action'     => $this->mailData['action'],
                      'object'     => $this->mailData['object'],
                  );

    return $this->view('emails.notification')
                ->with([
                    'inputs' => $input,
                  ]);
}
```

Comment: what is inside variable `$mailData?` an array?

Comment: its the data you have pass in mailable

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, the answer correct. But you can change the name variable $array to $data and check again. Maybe your variable name is a special case like array keyword

Comment: It still failed even though I already changed the variable name to $data

Comment: Can you give me the image of the error? I will  support you

Comment: When I run php artisan queue:listen. It just say `[2021-12-02 08:17:39][26] Failed:     App\Jobs\OrderEmailJob` without any error

Comment: For case:
I think you should run the command: php artisan queue:work and test UI trigger action in Controller. After check log

Comment: Yep, I've checked the document. You can update the code call the job:

`dispatch(new OrderEmailJob($data));`

And remove `$email = new OrderMail();` or add params for this